# How to send mail to the more than one users in php?

Tags: php, email

i am currently having problem sending mail to more than one users in php, i am able to send to one user at a time but the mail function only sends the mail to the first user and does not send the mail to the second one seperated by comma in `$to` variable.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
if($reg) {
        $to = "mail1@mail.com,mail2@mail.com";                           
        $from = "hootpile@hootpile.com";
        $subject = 'Hi VITian !';
        $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Hi VITian.</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><center>
<table id="ecxbodyTable" width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;background-color:#F2F2F2;height:100% !important;width:100% !important;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="ecxbodyCell" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:20px;border-top:0;height:100% !important;width:100% !important;">
<table id="ecxtemplateContainer" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:0;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="center" style="">
<table id="ecxtemplatePreheader" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxpreheaderContainer" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="center" style="">
<table id="ecxtemplateHeader" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxheaderContainer" valign="top" style="">
<table class="ecxmcnImageBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody class="ecxmcnImageBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnImageBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding:9px;">
<table class="ecxmcnImageContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right:9px;padding-left:9px;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;">
<a class="" style="word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank" title="" href="http://www.hootpile.com">
<img class="ecxmcnImage" width="90" align="left" style="max-width:125px;padding-bottom:0;display:inline !important;vertical-align:bottom;border:0;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" src="http://www.hootpile.com/userdata/profile_pics/BqUht7I39izV6Fn/resized_2015-04-10_1620.png" alt="Hootpile">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="center" style="">
<table id="ecxtemplateBody" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxbodyContainer" valign="top" style="">
<table class="ecxmcnTextBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody class="ecxmcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnTextBlockInner" valign="top" style="">
<table class="ecxmcnTextContentContainer" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnTextContent" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:9px;padding-left:18px;color:#606060;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:15px;line-height:150%;text-align:left;">
<h1 class="ecxnull" style="padding:0;display:block;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:40px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:-1px;text-align:left;color:#606060 !important;">
<strong style="color:#000000;display:block;font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;line-height:30px;text-align:left;text-transform:none;">
<span style="font-size:22px;">
<span style="color:#333333;font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:1.6em;">Join Hootpile Now.</span>
</span>
</strong>
</h1>
<p style="padding:0;color:#606060;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:15px;line-height:150%;text-align:left;">
<span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;font-family:courier,courier new,monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;text-align:left;">Hootpile is social utility that is transforming how students at VIT University connect with each other.</span>
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:courier,courier new,monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;"> We believe that students should be provided with a common platform to discuss everything, build anything. Hootpile is free from advertising, manipulation and  exploitation. </span>
<br>
<br>
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:courier,courier new,monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;">We can all be in one place but it starts from you, Join Now!</span>
<br>
<br>
<span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;font-family:courier,courier new,monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;text-align:left;">Simple, beautiful, and ad-free.</span>
<br>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="ecxmcnButtonBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody class="ecxmcnButtonBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnButtonBlockInner" valign="top" align="left" style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;">
<table class="ecxmcnButtonContentContainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:separate !important;border:2px solid #418bbc;border-radius:0px;background-color:#418bbc;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnButtonContent" valign="middle" align="center" style="font-size:16px;padding:15px;">
<a class="ecxmcnButton " style="font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:100%;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank" href="http://www.hootpile.com" title="Go to Hootpile">Go to Hootpile.</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="center" style="">
<table id="ecxtemplateFooter" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxfooterContainer" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:9px;">
<table class="ecxmcnTextBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody class="ecxmcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnTextBlockInner" valign="top" style="">
<table class="ecxmcnTextContentContainer" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ecxmcnTextContent" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:9px;padding-left:18px;color:#606060;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:11px;line-height:125%;text-align:left;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<span style="font-size:14px;">
<span style="font-family:courier new,courier,lucida sans typewriter,lucida typewriter,monospace;">
<span>
Visit the 
<a style="word-wrap:break-word;color:#606060;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" href="http://www.hootpile.com/manifesto">Hootpile Manifesto page.</a>
</span>
</span>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<span style="font-size:14px;">
<span style="font-family:courier new,courier,lucida sans typewriter,lucida typewriter,monospace;">
<strong>
<a style="word-wrap:break-word;color:#606060;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" href="http://www.hootpile.com">
<span style="color:#000000;">Hootpile.com</span>
</a>
</strong>
</span>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<span style="font-size:11px;">
<span style="font-family:courier new,courier,lucida sans typewriter,lucida typewriter,monospace;">
<span>
<span style="color:#D3D3D3;">If you dont want to receive </span>
<a target="_blank" style="word-wrap:break-word;color:#606060;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline;" href="http://ello.us3.list-manage2.com/unsubscribe?u=9ad48e023e0e67d4a8cda3fc9&id=eac7ac1a28&e=c73797a5f4&c=9d1407f6b5">
<span style="color:#D3D3D3;">emails</span>
</a>
<span style="color:#D3D3D3;">
from Hootpile
<br>
anymore, please
</span>
<a target="_blank" style="word-wrap:break-word;color:#606060;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.hootpile.com">
<span style="color:#D3D3D3;">unsubscribe here.</span>
</a>
<br>
<br>
<span style="color:#D3D3D3;">Hootpile, VIT University</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
</body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
<form id="new_user" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" name="reg" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: no errors as i mentioned i am able to get the mail on the first one and not on the second one.

Comment: Are you sure the email isn't being sent? Have you checked spam filters?

Comment: I believe you can specify BCCs in the header variables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple time mail() function :

```
$to = "hootpile@gmail.com, hootpile2@gmail.com";
foreach(explode(',', $to) as $mail) {
  mail(trim($mail), $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

That will send an email for each user.

Comment: @RahulKapoor the answer provided assumed a space would come after the comma, your original source did not perhaps that is why it's not working?